# SKYERROR: Code 1 Level 1 | File not found at /data/user/0/dad.droid.epubreaderlib/files/EpubReaderLib/books/Alice.epub

Tags: java, android, skyepub

Trying to build an epub reader in android studio with skyepub. The app opens with all the layout included but doesn't read the file.

Error: -

> SKYERROR : Alice.epub is not fount at
> /data/user/0/dad.droid.epubreaderlib/files/EpubReaderLib/books/Alice.epub
> or
> /data/user/0/dad.droid.epubreaderlib/files/EpubReaderLib/books/Alice/Alice.epub
> SKYERROR : Code 1  Level 1 SKYERROR : Error Detected while parseXML.
> SKYERROR : Code 10  Level 2 Error Detected while parseXML.

MainAppActivity looks like below :-

```
package dad.droid.epubreaderlib;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher;
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import com.skytree.epub.Highlight;
import com.skytree.epub.Highlights;
import com.skytree.epub.PageInformation;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class MainAppActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int bookCode;
    private LocalDb sd;

    final String TAG = "SKYEPUB";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     BookUtils.setStorageDirectory(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), "EpubReaderLib");
 BookUtils.makeDirectory("books");

        sd = new LocalDb(getApplicationContext());

        try {
            check();
            setup();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error while opening Book! Check Book Path. 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

bookCode = 1;        
String bookTitle = "Test Book";
String bookAuthor = "Book Author";
String bookFile = "Book.epub";
String bookState = "{}";
boolean isGlobalPaging = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("GLOBAL_PAGINATION", false);
        int theme = 0;

        try {
            check();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error while opening Book! Check Book Path. 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

if ("zip".equalsIgnoreCase(BookUtils.getFileExtension(bookFile))) {

String newBookFileName = bookFile.replaceAll("zip", "epub");
boolean status = BookUtils.setupHTML(getApplicationContext(), bookFile, newBookFileName.split("\\.")[0]);
            if (status) {
                bookFile = newBookFileName;
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error while opening Book! Check Book Path. 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }


if ("pdf".equalsIgnoreCase(BookUtils.getFileExtension(bookFile))) {
            //Launch PDF
            Toast.makeText(this, "Not yet supported!.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
            return;
        }

String targetBook = new BookUtils(getApplicationContext()).installBook(sd, bookCode, bookFile);

String filePath = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/EpubReaderLib/books/Alice.epub";
        Log.d("File Path", "Path: " + filePath);
}


    public void copyBookFromAssetsToDevice(String fileName) {
       
        try {
            String path = this.getStorageDirectory() + "/books/" + fileName;
            File file = new File(path);
            if (file.exists()) return;
            Context context;
            InputStream localInputStream = getAssets().open("books/" + fileName);
            FileOutputStream localFileOutputStream = new
                    FileOutputStream(this.getStorageDirectory() + "/books/" + fileName);
            byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[1024];
            int offset;
            while ((offset = localInputStream.read(arrayOfByte)) > 0) {
                localFileOutputStream.write(arrayOfByte, 0, offset);
            }
            localFileOutputStream.close();
            localInputStream.close();
            Log.d(TAG, fileName + " copied to phone");
        } catch (IOException localIOException) {
            localIOException.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAG, "failed to copy");
            return;
        }
    }

    void check() {
        String path = this.getStorageDirectory() + "/books/" + "Alice.epub";
        File file = new File(path);
        if (file.exists()) {
            Log.w(TAG, "File exists from check ");
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "File not exists");
        }
    }

    void setup() {

        try {
            if (isSetup()) return;
            this.makeDirectory("books");
            this.copyBookFromAssetsToDevice("Alice.epub");
            SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SkyMiniJ",0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = pref.edit();
            edit.putBoolean("isSetup", true);
            edit.commit();
        }catch(Exception e) {
        }
    }

    private boolean isSetup() {
        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("SkyMiniJ",0);
        return pref.getBoolean("isSetup",false);
    }

    public boolean makeDirectory(String dirName) {
        boolean res;
        String filePath = new String(this.getStorageDirectory() + "/"+dirName);
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            res = file.mkdirs();
        }else {
            res = false;
        }
        return res;
    }

    public String getStorageDirectory() {

        String res = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+getString(this.getApplicationInfo().labelRes);
        Log.d("Ress -->", "Storage Directory: " + res);
        return res;
    }

    public void onOpenBookPressed(View view) {
        Intent intent;
        intent = new Intent(this, BookActivityNew.class);
        intent.putExtra("BOOKCODE", 0);
        intent.putExtra("BOOKNAME", "Alice.epub");
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

InstallBook is in BookUtils class

```
 public String installBook(LocalDb sd, int bookCode, String file) {

        try {

            bookCode = sd.insertEmptyBook(bookCode, file, "", "", "", 0);
            String targetName = sd.getFileNameByBookCode(bookCode);

            Log.d("Install Book target", "Target Name?"+ targetName );
            Log.d("Install Book code", "Book code :" + bookCode );
            Log.d("Install Book Context", "Book file :" + file );

            copyBookToDevice(context, file, targetName);


            BookInformation bi;
            String coverPath = sd.getCoverPathByBookCode(bookCode);
            String baseDirectory = BookUtils.getStorageDirectory() + "/books";

            Log.d("Install Book Base", "Base directory :" + baseDirectory);



                    bi = getBookInformation(targetName, baseDirectory, coverPath);
            bi.bookCode = bookCode;
            bi.fileSize = -1;
            bi.downSize = -1;
            bi.isDownloaded = true;
            sd.updateBook(bi);
            return targetName;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

CopyBookToDevice method

```
    public static void copyBookToDevice(Context context, String source, String target) throws IOException {
        String path = getStorageDirectory() + "/books/" + target;
        File file = new File(path);
        if (file.exists()) return;
        //InputStream localInputStream = context.getAssets().open("books/" + source);
        InputStream localInputStream = new FileInputStream(context.getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/" + source);
        Log.d("Local Path mobile", "Check path :" + localInputStream);
        FileOutputStream localFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(getStorageDirectory() + "/books/" + target);

        byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[1024];
        int offset;
        while ((offset = localInputStream.read(arrayOfByte)) > 0) {
            localFileOutputStream.write(arrayOfByte, 0, offset);
        }
        localFileOutputStream.close();
        localInputStream.close();
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question and make sure, your [mcve] code only includes the parts relevant for answering your question?